# Do not have permission in

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions

I don't have permissions in SQL SERVER 2012 as every-time I execute a task whether it is a query or attaching database or granting permission through properties or anything else. I have tried all these things:

1. Uninstalled SQL Server.
2. Got Admin Right as well from admin team.
3. Opened as an administrator by right clicking on it.
4. Also taken help from stack overflow from related questions implemented too but didn't worked.

Comment: are you running a fresh install locally or are you talking about reinstalling SSMS?

Comment: It isn't about running SSMS as an administrator, it is about the database user permissions. Does the login you are using have sysadmin on the server you are connecting too? Perhaps you should check with your DBA to see if you are allowed to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: It was freshly installed earlier having same issues, than I reinstalled it. But having same results.

Comment: Please post an exact piece of code you are trying to execute, and the exact error message you are getting.  Your current question is too vague.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean..get it correct with the help of DBA

Comment: Really appreciate Benner, Tab and Noahp for guidance

Answer (score 0):

Try moving database file to C:\ level in the directory as SQL might not have access to the file at the current directory location.

Comment: a).CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'tempdb'.

Comment: b).On Attaching a database causing error:-An exception occur while executing transact-SQL statement or batch

Comment: c).The server principal "xxxx" is not able to access the database "model" under the current security context.( Microsoft SQL server , error:916)